# Use |... to diplay tabs in vim

Tags: vim

I feel like I have seen someone say on the web they did this and I find it very convenient.

I am trying to display tabs as

> |...

but when I enter to vim

```
:set listchars=tab:|.
```

I get following error

> E474: Invalid Argument: listchars=tab:

That very odd to me is that when looking at `:h listchars` neither pipe nor period are mentioned as forbidden characters( while ',' and ':' are forbiden)

Does anyone know why am I getting this error, and possible how can I get around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pipe character separates commands in vim. So you need to escape it

```
:set listchars=tab:\|.
```